# Replace the last character of a string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace, substring

I have this string :

```
 string lat ="24.6669863852163";
```

how can I replace the last Character '3' by '2' ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I just realized my mistake (which is why I deleted the comment as it was inaccurate and misleading).

Comment: question is not clear. Replacing only "3" by "2", or any character by precedent ? lat.Substring(0, lat.Length - 1) + (char)(lat[lat.Length - 1] - 1)

Answer (score 15):

```
lat = lat.Substring(0, lat.Length-1) + "2";
```

Comment: No offense, but why was there no **explanation?**

Answer (score 4):

```
lat = lat.Remove(lat.Length - 1) + "2";
```

Comment: `Substring` would be a **better choice** than `Remove`